# How do I center align my iFrameElement within HtmlElementView in flutter?

Tags: html, css, flutter, iframe, flutter-web

I am using an HtmlElementView in my **flutter web** project for showing a web image/pdf etc.
I am not able to figure out a way to align the element within the frame. As shown by the below sample code example, if the image size is smaller than parent widget size, it is shown in top left alignment. I have a feeling this has to do with some iframe style setting but not able to figure out.

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Material App Bar'),
      ),
      body: InteractiveViewer(
          child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              width: 3000,
              height: 3000,
              child: EmbedWebView(
                  src:
                      'https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300', //'https://www.youtube.com/embed/3fB1mxOsqJE',
                  width: 500,
                  height: 550))),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
    );
  }
}

class EmbedWebView extends StatefulWidget {
  final Key? key;
  final String src;
  final double height, width;
  EmbedWebView(
      {this.key, required this.src, required this.height, required this.width});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return EmbedWebViewState();
  }
}

class EmbedWebViewState extends State<EmbedWebView>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final IFrameElement _iframeElement = IFrameElement()
      ..height = '100%'
      ..width = '100%'
      ..src = widget.src
      ..style.border = 'none'
      ..style.overflow = "hidden"
      ..allow = "autoplay"
      ..allowFullscreen = true;
    // ignore: undefined_prefixed_name
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
      widget.src,
      (int viewId) => _iframeElement,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        width: widget.width,
        height: widget.height,
        child: HtmlElementView(
          // key: UniqueKey(),
          viewType: widget.src,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When the above code is run using flutter run -d chrome, this is what I get. It can be seen that the image in not centred.

[sample code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cglGQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the `EmvedWebView` with an `Expanded`. Probably the `EmvedWebView` is not occupying the whole `Container`, implying that even if the `Container` is centered his child is not

Comment: I guess you mean `HtmlElementView` instead of `EmbedWebView`. Doesn't help.  `HtmlElementView` is occupying the whole container.